# App crashes on launch - Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to android development and java programming. I have been following classes on Udacity with no problem, so I decided to start trying to create my first app on my own. It is a tip calculator. My app never opens when I try to run it in both the emulator and my Galaxy S6, it simply crashes right away. I've tried to review the logs and search through past threads on StackOverflow and other sites, but no solution has worked so far and I am absolutely lost. Can anyone please help me. I've only written java corresponding to the button that would display a 10% tip so far and ran into this error while testing it. I've attached my MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml and logcat below. I also added my AndroidManifest.xml as this seemed to be where most other people had a similar problem, but as I said I could not get any past solution to work. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please enter the total amount of your bill below."
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/check_total_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check Total: "
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/check_total"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Choose a percentage below, or enter a custom percentage to calculate your tip."
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ten"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="calcTenPercent"
        android:text="10%"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_fifteen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="15%"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_twenty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="20%"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_tip_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Custom Percentage:"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/custom_tip"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calc_custom_tip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate Custom Tip"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="24dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/final_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Tip Amount: "
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/final_tip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.tipcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

EditText checkTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.check_total);
String checkTotalValue = checkTotal.getText().toString();

double totalCheck = Double.parseDouble(checkTotalValue);

public void calcTenPercent(View view) {

    double tenPercent = 0.10;

    displayTip(totalCheck * tenPercent);

}

private void displayTip(double number) {

    TextView finalTip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.final_tip);
    finalTip.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.tipcalculator" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.tipcalculator.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**logcat**

```
07-27 20:59:13.331  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
    07-27 20:59:13.331  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator E/Zygote﹕ v2
    07-27 20:59:13.331  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10243
    07-27 20:59:13.331  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
    07-27 20:59:13.331  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SAMSUNG-SM-G920A_5.0.2_0011
    07-27 20:59:13.341  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
    07-27 20:59:13.341  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    07-27 20:59:13.351  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator D/TimaKeyStoreProvider﹕ TimaSignature is unavailable
    07-27 20:59:13.351  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator D/ActivityThread﹕ Added TimaKeyStore provider
    07-27 20:59:13.381  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
    07-27 20:59:13.381  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator I/InjectionManager﹕ Inside getClassLibPath caller
    07-27 20:59:13.391  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator D/InjectionManager﹕ InjectionManager
    07-27 20:59:13.391  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator D/InjectionManager﹕ fillFeatureStoreMap com.example.android.tipcalculator
    07-27 20:59:13.391  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator I/InjectionManager﹕ Constructor com.example.android.tipcalculator, Feature store :{}
    07-27 20:59:13.391  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator I/InjectionManager﹕ featureStore :{}
    07-27 20:59:13.411  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    07-27 20:59:13.411  23270-23270/com.example.android.tipcalculator E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.android.tipcalculator, PID: 23270
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.tipcalculator/com.example.android.tipcalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2197)
                at com.example.android.tipcalculator.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:20)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)`enter code here`
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

## UPDATED LOGCAT

The App now runs, but seems to terminate during the onClick. I will be working to resolve this issue and start a separate question should the need arise.

```
07-27 23:31:04.481  10846-10846/com.example.android.tipcalculator E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.tipcalculator, PID: 10846
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4273)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20983)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4268)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20983)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
        at com.example.android.tipcalculator.MainActivity.calcTenPercent(MainActivity.java:30)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4268)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20983)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

EditText checkTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.check_total);
String checkTotalValue = checkTotal.getText().toString();
```

Don't call findViewById in the global variable initialization which will called before the onCreate so the Activity still have no Content View (Which you will set on the onCreate).
So you can change your code to :

```
EditText checkTotal;
String checkTotalValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.check_total);
    checkTotalValue = checkTotal.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: Also, the next lines.

    `String checkTotalValue = checkTotal.getText().toString();` and `double totalCheck = Double.parseDouble(checkTotalValue);`

Comment: You're welcome :). And i was actually looking again at the code but it looks like he wants to get the text that the user will write probably, cause its an EditText... so probably he would only call those lines on a button click or something...@Toff_Tuning

Comment: @GeorgeR and @nayoso thank you so much. This definitely started pointing me in the right direction. @GeorgeR you are right, my idea is to get the text entered in the check_total EditText field when one of the buttons is clicked as to use it in the calculation. I edited the code to the above. I also had to move `double totalCheck = Double.parseDouble(checkTotalValue);` into my `public void calcTenPercent(View view)` in order for the app to run. The only problem is that now that it runs, it crashes once I try to click the 10% percent button with `android:onClick="calcTenPercent"` .

Comment: Sure Thing, I added the new error log to the end of the post. (Also, still new to Stack Overflow. If theres anyway that I should be posting differently, feel free to let me know) Thanks!

Comment: @Toff_Tuning looks like it's a different problem so you might need to post a new question. But I will give you a hint, your double is invalid and there is no value in it. You can try to check it with a debugger or a log. Please accept my answer if you think it's helpful.

Comment: No problem at all. I will try to figure out this new problem myself before starting a new question. Thanks again for all your help on the initial problem, and the hint as well. Both were extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
```

It seems as if you're passing in an empty double...maybe your `totalCheck` value isn't getting parsed correctly from the textfield?

Try taking a look at what your `checkTotal` contains when `checkTotalValue` is initialized, and then what you're passing into `displayTip`